# PowerShell - Error Changing AD Attributes

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Running a PowerShell script to update user attributes. I am using a test user to start with but everything seems in line. I tried the list file as both an Excel and CSV and get the same error. I matched up the data with the AD attributes as best as possible for simplicity. I'm missing something but cant see where it is.

Excel\CSV Data:

[image]

PowerShell code:

```
$users2 = import-excel "c:\orgstafflist2.xlsx"
foreach ($user in $users2) {get-aduser -filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($user.samaccountname)'" | set-aduser -displayname $($user.name) -surname $($user.last) -givenname $($user.first) -replace @{manager=$($user.manager)} -description $($user.description)}
```

Error Message:

```
set-aduser : The name reference is invalid
At line:1 char:97
+ ... ntname)'" | set-aduser -displayname $($user.displayname) -surname $($user.la ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=John Doe,OU=...riese,DC=office:ADUser) [Set-ADUser], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8373,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser
```

Comment: You can't set the `manager` attribute to any arbitrary string, like "Jane Doe" - it needs to be a reference to an existing object in the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First issue is your displayname column you try to reference with name in error. Second issue is you need to provide an AD user distinguished name for the manager.

```
$users2 = import-excel "c:\orgstafflist2.xlsx"
foreach ($user in $users2)
{
    get-aduser -filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($user.samaccountname)'" |
        set-aduser -displayname $($user.displayname) -surname $($user.last) -givenname $($user.first) -replace @{manager = $(get-aduser $user.Manager).distinguishedname} -description $($user.description)
}
```

You should also consider splatting for readability.

```
$users2 = import-excel "c:\orgstafflist2.xlsx"
foreach ($user in $users2)
{
    $UserParam = @{
        displayname = $user.displayname
        surname = $user.last
        givenname = $user.first
        replace = @{manager = (get-aduser $user.Manager).distinguishedname}
        description = $user.description
    }
    get-aduser -filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($user.samaccountname)'" | set-aduser @UserParam
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!! I actually found my issues a little after posting this but you are correct.